# Bootstrap-Select Data Live Search, search by data tokens AND value

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

When you use the bootstrap select picker with live search, it will search by whatever option values are.

But when you add data-tokens, it then only searches by the data tokens. Is there a way I can make it search by both? Or should I be using data-subtext instead so that both things are searchable?

Answer (score 0):

I did this by including the value in the data tokens. Ended up with options that looked like this

```
<option data-tokens='AVAS AV Accessories'>AV Accessories</option>
```

In this instance, the data-token only needed to be AVAS, the stock code for AV Accessories but I added the value since adding the token stopped the live search looking at the value.